# Do not use $A in LWC code error

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

```
var label = $A.get("$Label.c.ListOfDocumentsToExclude").split(',')
```

I am using above piece of code in LWC js to get custom label values. But, getting, " Do not use $A in LWC code error" while compile. Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$A` related to Aura Framework which is totally different from LWC.

For accessing labels in LWC you need to import it:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_labels

```
import labelName from '@salesforce/label/labelReference';
```